# laravel json select customer object select perticular data using hasMany

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

**how to select customer object select perticular data**

model user has connected to customer hasMnay

```
 public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Customer','employe_id','id');
    }
```

and user controller

```
$collection = User::with('customer')->where(['director_id'=> 16])->select('id','name',)->get();
        return $collection;
```

and response

```
[
    {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "emp1",
        "customer": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "shop_owner_name": "afs",
                "email": "a@gmail.com",
                "address": "a",
                "lat_lng": "a",
                "shop_name": "a",
                "shop_license": "a",
                "contact_number": "1234567890",
                "shop_image": "image/rU54qz67G9pJ7xEc8JSMkZAzxgUE5pb98zQPelMt.png",
                "customer_image": "image/0ylk6OfMGwOqsdcUXpVZapOpPL73oO0gtOk7PXYV.png",
                "director_id": 0,
                "employe_id": 25
            },
            
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: select what? what particular data of what table? what do you want the output to be?

Comment: customer in address,shop_owner_name

Comment: you can limit the select for that relationship but you will need to still select the foreign key `employee_id` so eloquent can match up the children to the parents

Comment: where are you thinking this `where` statement is supposed to be applied, as it doesnt look like your `users` has that field based on this output ... also `customer` should probably be `customers` (plural) so you know its a "many" relationship

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
$customers = [];
foreach($collection as $item) {

    $customers[] = $item->customer;
}

return $customers;
```

View

```
@foreach ($collection as $item)
    @foreach($item->customer as row)
        {{ $row->email }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = User::with('customer'=> function($query) {
     $query->select(['id','name']);
 })->where(['director_id'=> 16])->select('id','name',)->get();
        return $collection;
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
User::whereHas('customer', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('director_id', '=', 16);
})->get();
```

Try that!

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: not there return empty list in api postman

Comment: You may need to modify it more for your specific use case. The link is very informative.

Answer (score -1):

You can eager load specific columns
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

For your case if you want to only select `address` and `show_owner_name` of the customer:

```
$collection = User::with('customer:address,shop_owner_name')->where(['director_id'=> 16])->select('id','name',)->get();

return $collection;
```